# Should I use SqlString or string as parameter type to SQLCLR UDF's

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

What is the difference between the Sqlxxx datatypes and their .NET equivalents?

For instance, why and when should I use `SqlString` and not `string`?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever possible, you should use the `SqlTypes` types for SQLCLR method parameters. There are only 4 SQL Server datatypes that do not have a matching `Sql*****` type:

- `TIME`: use `TimeSpan` or `TimeSpan?`
- `DATETIME2`: use `DateTime` or `DateTime?`
- `DATETIMEOFFSET`: use `TimeZoneOffset` or `TimeZoneOffset?`
- `SQL_VARIANT`: use `object` (`NULL` comes through as `DbNull.Value`)

For more info, see the following MSDN page: [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Some differences between `SqlString` and `string` (that are important in certain situations) are that `SqlString`:

- retains the encoding as defined by the default COLLATION of the database where the Assembly exists, and
- contains properties describing the `LCID` and `SqlCompareOptions` (i.e. case sensitivity, accent sensitivity, etc) as defined by the default COLLATION of the database where the Assembly exists. Using `string` (or even `SqlChars`) would lose this info.
- has methods to return a `byte[]` -- [GetUnicodeBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.getunicodebytes.aspx) and [GetNonUnicodeBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.getnonunicodebytes.aspx) -- whereas `string` has `ToCharArray`. `NVARCHAR` source data is encoded as `UTF-16`, which will use either 2 bytes or 4 bytes for each character, depending on the character.
- properly handles T-SQL `NULL`s. This can be tested for via the `IsNull` boolean property (that all of the `Sql*` types have). When passing back as a return value or column value for a TVF, use the static property `SqlString.Null` (which all of the `Sql*` types have).

When it comes to sending in large values in `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)` parameters, you can actually stream the values from SQL Server into SQL Server's CLR by using the `SqlChars` and `SqlBytes` types, respectively. There are some use cases where streaming is much more efficient (assuming you don't need the entire value at one time). Also, if the parameter is never accessed, then none of the data is sent over at all, unlike when using `SqlString` and `SqlBinary`, respectively.

Related information can be found in an article I wrote for a series on SQLCLR: [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 5: Development (Using .NET within SQL Server)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration is required).

Answer (score 0):

A big difference is the null handling and collation. Look at the below link. 
I suggest using the sqlclr types for parameters and return types. 
You can typically work with these types in the whole function body.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131049(v=sql.100).aspx