# SQLCLR .NET Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, null, sqlclr

I am currently receiving an error when trying to execute a simple `SELECT` statement that references an assembly that contains the C# code for the Jaro-Winkler distance algorithm. This is my first time working with SQLCLRs.

I am able to run the code successfully below **without** the additional `OR` statement

Example:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    USERS
WHERE
(
    DATE_OF_BIRTH IS NOT NULL 
    AND DBO.JAROWINKLER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATE_OF_BIRTH,12),@DOB) > 0.9
)
OR
(
    USERID = @USERID
)
```

However when I include the `OR` statement I receive this error message:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "JaroWinkler":
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException: 
>      at JaroWinklerDistanceCLR.JaroWinklerDistance.proximity(String aString1, String aString2)

The code below works and does what is needed. I just wondered if there was another way? Ideally, I would like it contained to one `SELECT` statement. I have no idea what the error above is referring to, there are no `NULL` values in the `UserID` column.

The permission set for the assembly is set to Safe.

Working example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    USERS
WHERE
    DATE_OF_BIRTH IS NOT NULL 
    AND DBO.JAROWINKLER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATE_OF_BIRTH,12),@DOB) > 0.9

UNION ALL

SELECT
    *
FROM
    USERS
WHERE
    USERID = @USERID
```

Comment: So are you the author of the JAROWINKLER and asking how to fix the null reference exception?

Comment: @AlexK. No I am passing values to the distance algorithm. My problem is the "bolt-on" OR statement in SQL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other two answers are work arounds, not solutions. And this work-around will have to be duplicated in every place where this function is used, and that is very error-prone and difficult to maintain.

Before getting into the main problem here, there is a minor, related problem that should be fixed first: the input parameter types are incorrect. For SQLCLR methods, you should use the `Sql*` types instead of the standard .NET types. For this particular code, that means using `SqlString` instead of `String`. For more details on why `SqlString` instead of `String`, please see my answer to the following S.O. question: [Should I use SqlString or string as parameter type to SQLCLR UDF's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511885/should-i-use-sqlstring-or-string-as-parameter-type-to-sqlclr-udfs/31332212#31332212).

Now, the problem is that the SQLCLR code is not properly handling `NULL`s. Fortunately, it is not difficult to get it to handle them. There are two options, depending on if *any* of the input parameters can accept a `NULL` or not:

- If *any* of the input parameters can validly pass in a `NULL`, then you need to handle this in the code (and this also applies to all cases when working with Table-Valued Functions and Stored Procedures). And you check in the code via the `.IsNull` property that all of the `Sql*` types have. For example (assuming `aString2` can pass in a `NULL`):

  ```cs
  if (aString1.IsNull)
  {
    return SqlDouble.Null;
  }
  ```
- If *none* of the input parameters can validly accept `NULL`, then you should bypass all processing without entering the code in the first place by creating the Scalar UDF with the `WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` option of the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement. With this option set, if *any* input parameter is `NULL`, then the code is skipped and a `NULL` return value is assumed. Please note that this only works with Scalar UDFs and User-Defined Type methods.

For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series of articles I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central (free registration is required to read content on that site): [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).

---

On a related note, I would question the use of a string distance function to do what is a rather simple date calculation. I would think that this code would benefit greatly from replacing the JaroWinkler function with a `DATEDIFF` based on converting the string `@DOB` to `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Comment: Thank you, Solomon, this is extremely helpful. I will be implementing your suggestions.

Comment: @Zakerias You're welcome :-). And I just added a link to my answer on a question (also on S.O.) specifically about SqlString vs String.

Answer (score 1):

The OR statement is most likely including NULL values into your result set which are returning as a different data type. Try using

```
    OR (USERID = @USERID AND AND P.DATE_OF_BIRTH IS NOT NULL)
```

or, if you require the NULL values then select the field names explicitly (rather than select *) and wrap the date_of_birth field in a convert statement

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. `NULL` values in the date of birth field.

Working!

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    USERS
WHERE
(
    DBO.JAROWINKLER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ISNULL(P.DATE_OF_BIRTH,''),12),@DOB) > 0.9
)
OR
(
    USERID = @USERID
)
```