# SQL CLR randomly fails in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, httpwebrequest, sqlclr

I have created a .Net assembly and imported it into SQL Server and use it in a scalar-valued function (SVF).

When I execute the SVF it works fine. The second time also. But every third time the SVF fails and the underlying error is

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have added try/catch statements and debug data to the CLR, but I still have no clue as to why this CLR fails.

Can you help me out?

This is the C# code:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString HEAD(SqlString Uri)
{
    string statusCode = "";
    // Debug info
    string debugData = "1,";

    try
    {
        debugData += "2,";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        debugData += "3,";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString(Uri));

        req.Method = "HEAD";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        debugData += "4,";
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        debugData += "5,";

        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
        {
            // Use GET instead of HEAD
            debugData += "6,";
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString(Uri));
            req.Method = "GET";
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }

        debugData += "7,";
        statusCode = ((int)resp.StatusCode).ToString();
        debugData += "8,";
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        debugData += "9,";
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        debugData += "10,";
        statusCode = ((int)webResponse.StatusCode).ToString();
        debugData += "11,";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        debugData += "12,";
        statusCode = debugData + ex.Message;
        debugData += "13,";
    }
    debugData += "14,";
    //return (statusCode);
    return debugData;
}
```

The method takes a string as input (which is a URL) and checks if the URL actually exists by doing a HttpWebrequest with a HEAD method.

It returns the status code, or an error message (hence the string as output).

The assembly has been successfully imported into my database:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLHttpRequest
FROM N'C:\somefolder\SQLHttpRequest.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE;
GO
```

And this is the SVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_head_webrequest
    (@Uri nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME SQLHttpRequest.[SQLHttpRequest.HTTPFunctions].HEAD;
```

This is how I test this function:

```
declare @uri nvarchar(1000) = 'https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Microsoft_logo_SQL-700x566.png'
SELECT dbo.uf_head_webrequest(@uri)
```

The output is 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,14,

However, if I execute it a couple of times, I get this response:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> A .NET Framework error occurred during the execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "uf_head_webrequest":
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> System.NullReferenceException:
> at SQLHttpRequest.HTTPFunctions.HEAD(SqlString Uri)
> .

I understand the concept of object instantiation but don't understand why I don't get any debug data back.

I have searched the internet and came up with this question on SO:

[SQLCLR .NET Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352980/sqlclr-net-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

This describes problems with NULL values. But in my opinion, this is not the case here. Especially because I am using the same Uri again and again.

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing random about a NullReferenceException. It's *always* because someone tried to use a method or property on a `null` variable. This has nothing to do with SQLCLR. Using blocking operations like this in a database is a good way to cause lots of blocking too. It's far easier and more efficient to perform HTTP calls from client code

Comment: If you insist on initiating HTTP calls from the database, a better option would be to use SQL Server 2017's Python support or, in 2016, R. The code you posted allocates a lot of temporary strings in SQL Server's own memory. With Python, you could specify script in your command directly and the script would be executed outside SQL Server's process

Comment: I cannot stress enough what a horrifically terrible idea it is to make your DB server do HTTP calls. Managing/monitoring resource use, firewalling, rolling out new versions and troubleshooting when things fail is far more complicated than when you're doing it in client code (as you've experienced). "Performance" is not a good excuse, in any case; there are many ways to optimize data throughput from clients to the server (bulk copy, in memory table, etc.)

Comment: The server may limit the number of request that occur from same client.  I would put a using block around the request so it gets disposed at the end of each request.

Comment: Everything about what this is trying to do is terrible. Web requests from SQL, terrible. No `using` statements, terrible. Not using modern APIs for web requests, terrible. I don't know what's causing the NRE but I do know that you should take the hint and not try to perform these kinds of operations in a database server.

Comment: `ex.Response` can be `null`, as `WebException` won't have a response if there was no response (for example a connectivity issue).  I agree with everyone else in this thread, web requests from SQL sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be this line (in `catch (WebException ex)` ):

```cs
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
```

You are assuming that `ex.Response` exists. Try checking if it's `null` first. This would explain why you aren't getting the `debugData` value back (due to an unhandled exception in the error handling).

HOWEVER, even if that fixes the error, there are still several problems with this code, the biggest being:

1. not cleaning up disposable resources (i.e. no `using()`)
2. using `TRUSTWORTHY ON` (please see: [PLEASE, Please, please Stop Using Impersonation, TRUSTWORTHY, and Cross-DB Ownership Chaining](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/))
3. Unnecessarily setting the assembly to `UNSAFE` instead of `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`

Minor problems:

1. setting `DataAccessKind = Read` (you aren't doing data access and it's a performance hit; might not add to performance of this type of operation but still)
2. using `Convert.ToString(Uri)` instead of just `Uri.Value`

In the end, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel by coding your own HTTP request? There are several existing options of this exact function that are more functional and have gone through a bit of testing. There are one or two good free options I've seen on GitHub (don't just grab source from some blog as there are several rather bad examples out there), and there's a non-free option via my [SQL# (SQLsharp)](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_64915607) project (while there is a free version, the **INET_GetWebPages** function is only in the paid version) that I believe has some functionality not available in those free options (at least not as of the last time I checked).

Comment: Hi Solomon and others, thanks for your time and responses. Indeed the ex.response did not exist because of a time-out. However if I tested if for null, I would still get the exception and not the debug data. Apparently the timeout within SQL Server kicked in earlier and produced the exception. When I decrease the time-out value of the request, I do get a response back. I will be looking into your other suggestions (problems found) and work on a solution outside of SQL!

Comment: @Roeland In `catch (WebException ex)` you tested for `if (ex.Response != null)` before doing anything else and it throws an exception? Are you sure that the code is even going to that specific catch block? You could put a `throw new Exception("catch 1"?);` at the top of each `catch` block to see which one is being used. And for the record, I'm not in the "HTTP calls in SQL Server are pure evil" camp. They can be done, but with much care. They're fine for infrequent calls, such as maintenance. You can also use a separate Express instance for it, communicating to main instance via Linked Server.